# Executing Dynamic Sql query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a `SELECT` query in which i will have a a Dynamic `WHERE` condition. The thing is when I try to concatenate the `WHERE` condition `PARAMETER` with the SQL Query its not allowing me to save the `PROCEDURE`.

eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MySearchQuery
(
  QTYPE IN INT,
  OUT_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
DYN_QUERY VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
    IF QTYPE=1 THEN
       DYN_QUERY :=' BETWEEN 1 AND 2';
    ELSE
       DYN_QUERY :='=10';    
    END IF;

    OPEN OUT_CUR FOR
         SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TYPE=QTYPE AND ID || DYN_QUERY;
END;
```

This is how my procedure looks like.
I tried `EXECUTE IMMEDIETE` but in its documentation itself, its written it wont work for multiple row query.

In `MSSQL` we have `EXEC`(not sure) command which can `execute` the text sent to the command. In the same way do we have any commands which can run the dynamic query in `Oracle`

---

```
UPDATE: Answer
```

---

I tried like this.

```
  OPEN OUT_CUR FOR
        ' SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TYPE=:QTYPE AND ID ' || DYN_QUERY
          USING QTYPE;
```

and it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Dynamic* String has to be enclosed within 'Single Quotes'

```
OPEN OUT_CUR FOR
     'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID '|| DYN_QUERY;
```

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` allows Multi row result, if you use `BULK COLLECT` 
*Example:*

```
DECLARE
  TYPE myarray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
  v_array myarray;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ''x'' from dual union all select ''y'' from dual'
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_array;

  --Or you could use the alternative quoting mechanism to avoid doubling quotation marks.
  --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[select 'x' from dual union all select 'y' from dual]'
  --  BULK COLLECT INTO v_array;

  FOR i IN 1..v_array.count
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_array(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` using *bind variables*;

```
String := 'SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE name = :name AND age = :age AND :name <> ''Mahesh''';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE String USING 'Mahi',21,'Mahi';
<OR>
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE String USING proc_variable1,proc_variable2,proc_variable1;
```

Comment: I have a date conversion also inside it. ie. TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'). Now when i put the single quotes how it will work. I wrote Two single quotes... will it work?  ' SELECT ..... TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,''DD-MM-YYYY'')' will it work?

Comment: Your answer was correct. But i have one more problem which i thought will be solved when executing the query. In my stored procedure i'm having the Parameter in the where conditon too. So, when im running the query with single quotes its saying that the procedure parameter(QTYPE) inside the select query is Invalid. I thought of putting Single quotes and Joining it as a string but, Im worried about SQLInjection.

Comment: you can also you bind variable !!Like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ''x'' from dual where :x = 1' USING v_x` Also applies for `OPEN CURSOR`

Comment: @smilu You can also try out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405616/oracle-sql-injection-block-with-dbms-assert/21406499#21406499) which explains about `DBMS_ASSERT` package

Comment: I put : and its showing another error all variables are not bound :(

Comment: you use same variable name two times? you have to specify in `USING` too same number of _bind_ variable inputs..

Comment: any examples i can refer?

Comment: Added few to my answer!